# Remove meta from reply_html_page

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, frameworkbenchmarks

How do I remove the `meta` tag that is automatically inserted by `reply_html_page`?

```
reply_html_page(
    [title('Fortunes')],
    [table([
        ...
    ])]
).
```

The generate code looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
  <head>
    <title>Fortunes</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Additionally: Is there a way to send the `Content-Length` header with the response?

Cross-Post: https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/remove-meta-from-reply-html-page/4189

Comment: Ahh, you have asked a question very specific to SWI-Prolog. Try asking at the [SWI-Prolog forum](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/). If you do and don't delete this question here at least note in both places that the question is [cross posted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossposting).

Comment: It seems you have an [answer](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/remove-meta-from-reply-html-page/4189/8?u=ericgt) you will accept from the SWI-Prolog forum by [Jan Wielemaker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/717069/jan-wielemaker). I don't think Jan W. will be replying here so maybe you should post it as an answer, add some comments explaining the code and get some more points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me (answered by @jan-wielemaker here: https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/remove-meta-from-reply-html-page/4189/8)

```
reply(_Request) :-
    ...,
    phrase(page([ head(title('Fortunes')),
                  body(table(\sequence(row, Rows)))
                ]),
           Tokens),
    print_html(Tokens).

row(row(N, C)) -->
    html(tr([td(N), td(C)])).
```

Comment: Basically how this solves the problem is that it drops down to lower level code to create the HTML response. The question used [reply_html_page/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=reply_html_page/2) which generates the undesired meta line. Using [page/1](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=page//1) did not generate the meta line.